# Socket.ConnectAsync receives 400 bad request while Socket.Connect gets 200 ok

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

I want to connect to a service using socket. When I use Socket.Connect, the response is 200 ok and I can receive the data successfully, but when I use Socket.ConnectAsync the response is 400 bad request.

Here is the code for Socket.Connect:

```
SocketAsyncEventArgs myev;
private void Receive(SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
{
    myev = e;
    SocketAsyncEventArgs readEventArgs = m_readWritePool.Pop();
    readEventArgs.RemoteEndPoint = remote;
    Socket connectSocket;
    connectSocket = new Socket(remote.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    connectSocket.Connect(remote);//Sync Connect 
    ProcessConnect(readEventArgs);
}
private void ProcessConnect(SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
{
    AsyncUserToken token = (AsyncUserToken)myev.UserToken;
    if (myev.BytesTransferred > 0 && myev.SocketError == SocketError.Success)
    {
        e.SetBuffer(myev.Offset, myev.BytesTransferred);
        bool willRaiseEvent = ((AsyncUserToken)e.UserToken).Socket.SendAsync(e);
        if (!willRaiseEvent)
        {
            ProcessServerSend(e);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        CloseClientSocket(e);
    }
}
```

and here is the code for Socket.ConnectAsync:

```
SocketAsyncEventArgs myev;
private void Receive(SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
{
    myev = e;
    SocketAsyncEventArgs readEventArgs = m_readWritePool.Pop();
    readEventArgs.RemoteEndPoint = remote;
    Socket connectSocket;
    connectSocket = new Socket(remote.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    ((AsyncUserToken)readEventArgs.UserToken).Socket = connectSocket;
    bool willRaiseEvent = connectSocket.ConnectAsync(readEventArgs);//Async Connect
    if (!willRaiseEvent)
    {
        ProcessConnect(readEventArgs);
    }

}
private void ProcessConnect(SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
{
    AsyncUserToken token = (AsyncUserToken)myev.UserToken;
    if (myev.BytesTransferred > 0 && myev.SocketError == SocketError.Success)
    {
        e.SetBuffer(myev.Offset, myev.BytesTransferred);
        bool willRaiseEvent = ((AsyncUserToken)e.UserToken).Socket.SendAsync(e);
        if (!willRaiseEvent)
        {
            ProcessServerSend(e);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        CloseClientSocket(e);
    }
}
```

Note that we have defined `m_readWritePool` as `SocketAsyncEventArgsPool m_readWritePool;` and filled it with 1000 items.

We have defined `ProcessServerSend` as:

```
private void ProcessServerSend(SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.SocketError == SocketError.Success)
    {                
        AsyncUserToken token = (AsyncUserToken)e.UserToken;
        SocketAsyncEventArgs readEventArgs = m_readWritePool.Pop();
        ((AsyncUserToken)readEventArgs.UserToken).Socket = token.Socket;         
        bool willRaiseEvent = token.Socket.ReceiveAsync(readEventArgs);
        if (!willRaiseEvent)
        {
            ProcessServerReceive(readEventArgs);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        CloseServerSocket(e);
    }
}
```

And `ProcessServerReceive` is as:

```
private void ProcessServerReceive(SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
{                   
    AsyncUserToken token = (AsyncUserToken)myev.UserToken;
    if (e.BytesTransferred > 0 && e.SocketError == SocketError.Success)
    {
        myev.SetBuffer(e.Offset, e.BytesTransferred);
        byte[] buf = new byte[e.BytesTransferred];
        for (int i = 0; i < e.BytesTransferred; i++)
        {
            buf[i] = e.Buffer[e.Offset + i];
        }
        string message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buf);
        //The message contains '200 ok' or '400 bad request' when using Connect or ConnectAsync respectively.
        bool willRaiseEvent = token.Socket.SendAsync(myev);
        if (!willRaiseEvent)
        {
            ProcessSend(myev);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        CloseServerSocket(e);
    }
}
```

Note that all the functions are the same but the connect method! I have check that the message which is sent is as the same!

---

**Update:**

The response is:

Bad Request - Invalid Verb

HTTP Error 400. The request verb is invalid.

Comment: Where are you passing myev to the async connect method?

Comment: @jdweng actually I'm using this code to get data from a socket A and send it to another socket B and receive the response from B and send it back to A. `myev` is a `SocketAsyncEventArgs` which is dedicated for receiving data from A, so to connect to B I have defined a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of this problem is due to connecting using a `SocketAsyncEventArgs` variable with a buffer initialized by 1024 elements (1024 element empty buffer). I have solved the problem by adding this line of code: `readEventArgs.SetBuffer(0, 0);` before `Async Connect` setting a zero length buffer. So, my `Receive` function has been changed to:

```
private void Receive(SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
{
    myev = e;
    SocketAsyncEventArgs readEventArgs = m_readWritePool.Pop();
    readEventArgs.RemoteEndPoint = remote;
    Socket connectSocket;
    connectSocket = new Socket(remote.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    ((AsyncUserToken)readEventArgs.UserToken).Socket = connectSocket;
    readEventArgs.SetBuffer(0, 0);//This line of code resolves my issue.
    bool willRaiseEvent = connectSocket.ConnectAsync(readEventArgs);//Async Connect
    if (!willRaiseEvent)
    {
        ProcessConnect(readEventArgs);
    }
}
```